# Forwarding of parameters from templates to functions of different types

Tags: c++

I was experimenting with templates and forwarding. Wrote some simple experimental code which surprised me. I would like to better understand this mechanism, probably I lack some knowledge here and therefore I ask for help. Could you please explain why the two of my calls in the code below don't compile (PLACE 2 and 3)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

void h2rvalref(int&& i) { cout << "h2rvalref" << endl; }
void h2ref(int& i) { cout << "h2ref" << endl; }
void h2val(int i) { cout << "h2val" << endl; }

template <class T, class X>
void h1(T&& t, X x) { x(forward<T>(t)); }

int main()
{    
    // PLACE (1)
    h1<int, decltype(h2rvalref)>(1, h2rvalref);

    auto b = 1;
    // PLACE (2)
    // h1<int, decltype(h2ref)>(b, h2ref); // --> ERROR - no matching function..., cannot convert 'b' (type 'int') to type 'int&&'

    // PLACE (3)
    // h1<int, decltype(h2val)>(b, h2val); // --> ERROR - no matching function..., cannot convert 'b' (type 'int') to type 'int&&'
}
```

I don't understand why the error says something about converting int to int&& when I have value b of type int.

Comment: Don't comment out the code that you're asking about. The syntax highlighting makes it hard to read.

Comment: Ok, I'll remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are providing explicit template arguments to the function. Forwarding arguments does not work when you explicitly provide the template arguments for the type you want to forward (unless you really know what you are doing).

> ```
> template <class T, class X>
> void h1(T&& t, X x) { x(forward<T>(t)); }
> ```

When you write `h1<int, decltype(h2ref)>`, you get a function like this:

```
void h1(int&& t, decltype(h2ref) x) { x(forward<int>(t)); }
```

`int&&` is a different type from `int` and cannot be bound to an lvalue of type `int` such as the `b` that you pass in; it can only be bound to rvalues of type `int`

---

If you leave off the template arguments, it just works:

```
h1(b, h2ref);
```

This will instantiate a function that looks like this:

```
void h1(int& t, // int& && collapses to just int&
        decltype(h2ref) x) {
    x(forward<int&>(t));
}
```

Comment: "int&& is a different type from int and cannot be implicitly created from int" IMHO, this is a very shady explanation. `int` is a type, and `int&&` can bind to expressions of that type, but only if the value category of that expression (different from type) is rvalue. The problem occurs because an `int&&` cannot bind to an lvalue of type `int`.

Comment: @NirFriedman Why is it a problem to view `int`, `int&`, and `int&&` as completely distinct types with conversion rules that match up with lvalue/rvalue rules of C++?

Comment: They *are* distinct types, but the "cannot be implicitly created from int" has multiple issues. The first is that reference is not like a normal C++ type that gets created from another type implicitly/explicitly, instead references have binding rules, they are bound. Second is that the gist of your original statement is not even true; `int&&` can bind to `int` in some cases but not in others. Third is that that your way of looking at things, in addition to mixing up type construction and binding, also mixes together type and value category, which need to be understood separately.